# Distingushing between user and non-user types & templates specialization

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, c++14, template-specialization

I need to somehow overload class templates for user and non-user types. The problem arises from the point that template class inherits from the template parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<type_traits>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Broken_imput{};//exception class
class No_such_class{};

class Io_obj; // For MAP to know about this type

//MAP: KEY - String, VALUE - function pointer
map<string,Io_obj*(*)(istream&)> func_storage;

bool read_string(istream& ss,string& str)
{
    if(ss>>str)return true; // read string from the given source
    return false;
}
//------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------
////CLASS THAT SETS THE INTERFACE///////////////
class Io_obj
{
public:

    virtual ~Io_obj(){}
    virtual void print_data()= 0;
};

//-------------------------------------------------
//FUNCTION THAT READS OBJECTS LOOKS FOR THE APPROPRIATE  METHOD IN MAP AND CALLS
// IT IF METHOD EXIST. METHOD READS OBJECT OF THE TYPE IT KNOWS FROM GIVEN STREAM
Io_obj* read_object(istream& stream)
{
    string str;
    if(!read_string(stream,str)) throw Broken_imput{};
    if(auto FN=func_storage[str])return FN(stream);
    throw No_such_class{};

}
////////////////SOME CLASSES//////////////////////////////////

struct Shape
{
    string data;
};

struct Circle:public Shape{};

template < class T,class = enable_if_t<is_class<U>::value,U >>
class Io:public T,public Io_obj
{
public:
    Io(istream& stream){ stream>>T::data;}
    void print_data() override
    {
        cout<<T::data<<endl;
    }

    //read value
   static  Io_obj* read_value(istream& stream) { return new Io{stream};} //deligate to constructor

};
```

As you cas see, ***class Io*** inherits from template parameter. In case of non-user types *(e.g. int,float,char*...) the code won't be compiled ( of course it shouldn't be ). I need somehow to write specialization for this template for the non-user types.The tag dispatch & object factories help, but I'd like to avoid them. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be something like

```
template<class T, bool = std::is_class<T>::value>
class Io:public T,public Io_obj
{ /* ... */ };


template<class T>
class Io<T, false> : public Io_obj
{ /* ... */ };
```

If the two specializations share a substantial amount of code, you may want to put it in a base class to reduce code duplication.

You can use `enable_if_t` for this too (though not in the way depicted in the question), but it's unnecessarily convoluted:

```
template<class T, class = void>
class Io:public T,public Io_obj
{ /* ... */ };


template<class T>
class Io<T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_class<T>::value>> : public Io_obj
{ /* ... */ };
```

Comment: Could you explain how to solve this problem using enable_if?(shortly,just to feed my curiosity:)

Answer (score 0):

Look more closely at facilities in the standard header `<type_traits>`.   For example `std::is_class<X>::value` is `true` if `X` is a non-union class type, and `false` otherwise.    These facilities can be used to support specialisations like you seek.